# I partitioned on event timestamp field by DAY in BigQuery, but the number of partitions is still displaying 0 given the 14 days of data. Why?

Tags: google-bigquery

Here's the image that shows that the table is partitioned on the event timestamp by DAY:
[image]

Here's the image that shows that the table contains 0 number of partitions, even though there are 14 days of data so far in the table.
[image]

Does this mean that the partitioning on event timestamp is not working? I'm expecting the number of partitions to be 14 with respect to 14 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take some time for the partitions to show up in this summary view

Comment: Thanks. Just checked and it reflects the correct number